# How to make Doctrine reject an entity if a property has an empty string value?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to prevent empty string insertion into MySQL database via doctrine,

I did this :

```
 /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
   * @Assert\NotBlank() ( or NotNull() )
   */
    private $name;
```

And I still get no errors when inserting empty input post value,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement [your own custom entity validation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/cookbook/validation-of-entities.html). The `Assert` annotations are used by the `Validator` component, but not by Doctrine.

For example, you could do something like this:

```php
/**
 * @Entity
 * @HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Thing
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @PrePersist @PreUpdate
     */
    public function assertNotEmptyName() {
        if(empty($this->name)) { 
            throw new ThingWithNoNameException();
        }
    }
}
```

Before creating or updating a `Thing` entity `assertNotEmptyName()` would be called, and would throw an exception if `name` were empty.

Additionally, I've added `nullable=false` so it's clear at DB level that the name cannot be `null`, for greater data integrity.

(The `ThingWithNoNameException` you'd have to define as well, logically).